# In Bonjour how do I hook up a web server to advertised port?

Tags: node.js, express, bonjour

I am trying to advertise a web service on a random port and then hook up a Node/Express server to listen to that port.

I tried to implement it with the following code (ES6):

```
import express from 'express';
import bonjour from 'bonjour';
import http from 'http';
import getPort from 'get-port'; // to generate random port

const advertisedPort = await getPort();
const server = bonjour();
const service = server.publish({name:'MyWebServer', port: advertisedPort, type: http});

const app = express();
app.get('/', (res, req) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(advertisedPort);
```

And I get an `EADDRINUSE`. If I use another port number in `.listen()`, the server comes up successfully. However, what I really want to do is to advertise a single port and then be able to listen to requests on that port.

Comment: Works fine for me (although `type : http` should be `type: 'http'`). Tested on macOS and Linux.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep for pointing out the typo. My code does have http in quotes, but I made an error in this post. I will investigate some more and try to figure out why it is not working for me. I am in Windows 10, so maybe that is a factor too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm folks. A reboot fixed it. Sorry to bother everybody

Comment: Feel free to close your question :)

Comment: Yeah ... waiting for the 2 day window to expire. Not allowed to accept my own answer for another 24 hrs. Thanks for your help @robertklep :)